# How to calculate average work length of a Pandas series of long strings

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a series that comes from a Pandas DataFrame

```
19607    uhmm i guess i start wit my name.. trung<br />...
6205     you could say my interests revolve around tech...
57858    i always find it difficult to sum myself up wi...
29471    loyal, witty, silly, understanding, dedicated,...
47277    so basically, i hate these "fill in your own w...
25535    i am ending a relationship with a woman right ...
51731    i work and live in san francisco. i enjoy what...
19106    i love being outside when the sun is out. i <a...
18594    i've met someone and am in a long-term relatio...
7326     humanitarian, teamplayer, great work ethic, re...
```

I want to calculate the **average word length** of each row. How do I go about achieving it?

Comment: kindly accept one of the answers as solution by clicking checkmark next to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `str.split` to split the sentences into words. Then `explode` and `str.len`:

```
s.str.split().explode().str.len().mean(level=0)
```

And you would get something like this:

```
0
19607    4.000000
6205     5.250000
57858    4.000000
29471    9.000000
47277    4.000000
25535    4.000000
51731    4.000000
19106    3.545455
18594    4.555556
7326     7.333333
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, I have:

1. removed punctuation (but kept spaces) as that shouldn't be part of the count
2. split on spaces
3. calculated the mean with list comprehension
4. joined with the original series, so you can see the results side-by-side

---

```
import re
import numpy as np
# s = pd.Series(d[1]) # I have called you pandas series "s" from your StackOverFlow question. If it is called something else change from s.apply to your_series.apply
s1 = (s.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^a-z|\s]', '', x))
      .str.split('\s+')
      .apply(lambda x: np.mean([len(y) for y in x])))
df = pd.concat([s,s1], axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
                                                       1         1
0                                                                 
19607  uhmm i guess i start wit my name.. trung<br />...  3.200000
6205   you could say my interests revolve around tech...  4.875000
57858  i always find it difficult to sum myself up wi...  3.700000
29471  loyal, witty, silly, understanding, dedicated,...  7.400000
47277  so basically, i hate these "fill in your own w...  3.500000
25535  i am ending a relationship with a woman right ...  3.700000
51731  i work and live in san francisco. i enjoy what...  3.600000
19106  i love being outside when the sun is out. i <a...  3.090909
18594  i've met someone and am in a long-term relatio...  4.000000
7326   humanitarian, teamplayer, great work ethic, re...  6.333333
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain? Coz when I run `s.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[a-z|\s]', '', x))`, I get `1        :.</>1..</>2..</>3..</>4.1-3.</>...'.........;...
3                     ...,,...</>,,.....</>&;/</>,,...</>.`